# Eclipse, exit code 13

Tags: eclipse, exit

I am using java 1.6. I have 64 bit W7OS. When I start Eclipse, I receive the exit code=13 error message. 
I have seen some solutions for this and I went into the eclipse.ini file and added in the path to java 1.6. This is the .ini file now. I added in the '-vm' and the following line of C:...

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

I understand that the Internet thinks that this has to do with my OS being 64-bit and Eclipse trying to run 32 bit version or something, but I do not understand the solutions given for that. What should I do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try reinstalling your Java or upgrading to (64-bit) Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reinstall java.

Go to `C:\Program Data\Oracle\java` and check the path the shortcuts `java`, `javaw` and `javaws` are pointing to.

If the shortcuts are not pointing to the correct 64-bit java path, delete the shortcuts and create new ones with the same name and change the target location of the program to the 64bit java (jdk\bin{java or javaws or javaw}) location.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and was generated by the symlinks in C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath the javaw symlink was pointing to the 32bit version.
I removed and created a new javaw symlink whith this command on the command prompt running as admin: mklink \javaw "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin"
The last arg og the command is where 64bit javaw is placed.

Hope this helps!